# Import GeoJSON in QGIS with file name as layer name?

Tags: qgis, geojson

When I add a GeoJSON layer to my QGIS project, it always gets the name "filename name_field_value".

For example, file named CZ0100554782.geojson is as layer in QGIS named "CZ0100554782 Praha"

I need import in QGIS thousands GeoJSON files, is it possible to have layers named only as file?

Comment: Without using python?

Comment: Can you add the header of your geojson?